# Resource Errors on 1G interfaces in Juniper router

Tags: routing, errors

We are observing resource errors on almost many 1G links on Juniper MX240. The resource errors counter is quite high. The MPC type is MPC Type 1 3D. I am sharing the output of command 'show interface extensive | match Error' as an example.

Can some one clarify what is meant by resource errors and why they occured? How to rectify them?

Junos OS is 15.1R5-S3.4

Many Thanks

//

```
R1> show interfaces ge-1/0/1 extensive | match Error    
  Link-level type: Flexible-Ethernet, MTU: 1522, MRU: 1530, LAN-PHY mode, Speed: 1000mbps, BPDU Error: None, MAC-REWRITE Error: None, Loopback: Disabled,
  Input errors:
    Errors: 0, Drops: 0, Framing errors: 0, Runts: 0, Policed discards: 0, L3 incompletes: 0, L2 channel errors: 0, L2 mismatch timeouts: 0, FIFO errors: 0,
    Resource errors: 11485 <-----
  Output errors:
    Carrier transitions: 1, Errors: 0, Drops: 0, Collisions: 0, Aged packets: 0, FIFO errors: 0, HS link CRC errors: 0, MTU errors: 0, Resource errors: 0
    CRC/Align errors                         0                0
    FIFO errors                              0                0
    Total errors                             0                0
    Output packet error count                                 0

R1> show interfaces ge-1/0/3 extensive | match Error    
  Link-level type: Flexible-Ethernet, MTU: 1518, MRU: 1526, LAN-PHY mode, Speed: 1000mbps, BPDU Error: None, MAC-REWRITE Error: None, Loopback: Disabled,
  Input errors:
    Errors: 5, Drops: 0, Framing errors: 5, Runts: 0, Policed discards: 0, L3 incompletes: 0, L2 channel errors: 0, L2 mismatch timeouts: 0, FIFO errors: 0,
    Resource errors: 7433 <-----
  Output errors:
    Carrier transitions: 17, Errors: 0, Drops: 0, Collisions: 0, Aged packets: 0, FIFO errors: 0, HS link CRC errors: 0, MTU errors: 0, Resource errors: 0
    CRC/Align errors                         5                0
    FIFO errors                              0                0
    Total errors                             6                0
    Output packet error count                                 0
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this juniper document](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/concept/using-show-commands-for-packet-drops.html) it is the sum of transmit drops. [This Juniper forum post](https://forums.juniper.net/t5/Junos/Ethernet-Interface-Resource-Errors/td-p/33505) explains it a bit more:

> Basically, when a packet cannot be either put in the buffer or retrieved from the buffer (i.e. when packet is scattered across several buffers due to the pkt size and one of the buffers cannot be accessed) then this counter increments.

I personally have never observed these kinds of errors and have no idea how bad they are or how to get rid of them. I’d open a TAC case for that if I were you.

Comment: Thanks Teun. I personally went through the same Juniper forum page that you mentioned. I just wanted to have more detailed picture of reasons why such errors occurred.